# Function similar to arithmetic mean that amplifies outliers?

Tags: functions

This is kind of an odd question, and I'm not well educated in math, but bear with me.

I need a procedure similar to taking the average of a bunch of numbers, except I want large changes in one of the values in the input to cause a larger change in the output than you get with normal arithmetic mean.

Basically I want {2, 2, 2, 5} to "average" to something a little bit more than 3, and {2, 2, 2, 100} to "average" to something a *lot* more than 26.5.

Does that make sense? Is there a function that behaves like this?

Comment: Can I ask why you need this?

Comment: @BenLongo Basically, I need a set of pixels to have colors "flow" through them. The way I have it now, each pixel's color is the average of the color of all adjacent pixels. The trouble is that changes in color are nullified more quickly than I want.

Comment: Interesting, have you looked into using something like a Gaussian matrix for weights? You may also want to check [this](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly well-known mean that may suit your needs is the [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), which is the square root of the mean of the squares.

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(2^2+2^2+2^2+5^2)}\approx 3.04$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}(2^2+2^2+2^2+100^2)}\approx 50.03$$

This is an example of a [power mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Power_mean).  $m=2$ gives the above, $m=1$ gives the arithmetic mean.  If you want more extreme means, just let $m$ get larger.